# Search for string and then print a word (defined by spaces only) after it

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I got a file that contains i.e:

```
Diameter is defined by... diameter 26.5/9 diameter has been changed
diameter has changed and then DIAMETER 942/10 yada di yada Diameter
```

In output i want:

```
26.5/9
942/10
```

As far as I understand:

I need to search for case insensitive string "diameter" that is followed by space and numeric character than go back to "diameter" and print following string between spaces.

I've only managed to came up with something like this:

```
sed -n '/^.*diameter\s\+\(\w\+\).*$/s//\1/p'
```

but it only prints single word (separated by non-alphanumeric) following a first occurence of case sensitive word "diameter". Output would look like this:

```
26
has
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk` written and tested in GNU `awk`. Using GNU `awk`'s `IGNORECASE` option so that it can match both `diameter` and `DIAMETER` in regex. Using `awk`'s `match` function to match regex `diameter [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\/[0-9]+` which will match diameter followed by space followed by digits followed by optional dot and digits followed by digits to get diameter values.

```
awk -v IGNORECASE="1" '
match($0,/diameter [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\/[0-9]+/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Using `awk`'s `RS` capability here, mentioning regex(same explained in above 1st solution) and in main program in RT value splitting it into array arr and printing 2nd part of arr which is diameter value.

```
awk -v RS='(diameter|DIAMETER) [0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?\\/[0-9]+' '
RT{
  split(RT,arr)
  print arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using `sed` written and tested in GNU `sed`. Using `-E` option of `sed` to enable ERE(extended regular expressions) here. Then in main program matching everything till `diameter` OR `DIAMETER` from starting of value, followed by spaces followed by same regex mentioned above in a capturing group(a feature in `sed` to save values into temp buffer to be used later on) and substituting whole line's value with captured part only.

```
sed -E 's/.*(diameter|DIAMETER)\s+([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\/[0-9]+).*/\2/' Input_file
```

---

---

***4th solution:*** With GNU `grep` using regex try following. Using `grep`'s `-o` and `-P` options to print only matched part and enable PCRE regex respectively. In main program doing a lazy match from starting of value till `diameter` OR `DIAMETER` string followed by spaces, then using `\K` option to FORGET all mathed values till here. Which is followed by regex which will print the required value by OP.

```
grep -oP '.*?(?:diameter|DIAMETER)\s+\K[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\/[0-9]+' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
26.5/9
942/10
```

Comment: sed doing it nicely
what if there's dots mixed with commas i.e

26.5/8
but
26,6/8

Comment: @Kuń, then in that case try `sed -E 's/.*(diameter|DIAMETER)\s+([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?\/[0-9]+).*/\2/' Input_file` try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: no it's not...
,7
,5
,5
,5

I've just simply substituted commas to dots

Answer (score 1):

You can also use grep:

```
$ grep -Pio '(?<=diameter\s)[\d.\/]+(?=\s)' input_file
26.5/9 
942/10
```

---

- `(?<=)`: Positive lookbehind.
- `diameter\s`: Matches `diameter` .
- `[\d.\/]`: Matches either a digit, a dot or a slash.
- `+`: Matches the preceding token between one and unlimited times (greedy).
- `(?=)`: Positive lookahead.
- `\s`: Matches a white space.

---

- `-P`: Perl style regex.
- `-i`: Case insensitive.
- `-o`: Print only matching part.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed for `i` to make the match case-insensitive:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*diameter \([0-9][^ ]*\).*/\1/pI' file
26.5/9
942/10
```

With any sed+tr:

```
tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' file | sed -n 's/.*diameter \([0-9][^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```